# Is pyc file of build-in modules are also created?

Tags: python-3.x

Is pyc file of build in modules are also created?

My Scenario:
I had a file abc.py.

In abc.py, I had imported os modules and the print os.getcwd().

Here, I was expecting os.pyc file must be created, but os.pyc was not created.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on your installation but builtin modules and distribution packages are cached in system locations. 
Here's how you can find them:

- Import the module
- Get the file where it was loaded from `module.__file__`
- Go to that location
- Look for a folder `__pycache__`
- Look inside that folder

```
➜  ~ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py'
>>> 
➜  ~ ll /usr/lib/python3.6/os.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37K Oct 22  2018 /usr/lib/python3.6/os.py
➜  ~ ll /usr/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/os*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29K Dec  3 20:37 /usr/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/os.cpython-36.pyc
➜  ~
```

The builtin and dist-packages are cached globally so that all scripts can use them.

The location will be slightly closer to your script in case you're using a `virtualenv`